# Not Showing screenshots on iPad for the app store iphone app

Tags: ios, ipad, itunes, screenshot

I have recently submitted my iPhone app to app store , While submitting i have uploaded the screenshots of size 960x 640 . As for Mac and iPhone all the five screen are visible but for iPad two screen are missing .

But if we tab on the screen shots , all the five can be viewed while scrolling .